# Chamada do postman não entra no construtor da controller com parâmetro

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Peguei um projeto já desenvolvido, mas com vários problemas. Na controller que eu estou trabalhando, coloquei um break no construtor com um parâmtero e não entra. Se eu defino um sem parâmetro e mantenho o outro(com parâmetro), o break para no sem parâmetro e não no com parâmetro. O cenário estava assim:
1) A injeção estava sendo feito por um objeto e não uma Interface, como é comum. É possível eu injetar um objeto? A minha solução para testes foi: Comentei tudo, criei uma interface com um método, na classe Orcamento, e injetei no construtor da controller, mas isso também não funcionou. Veja a controller como está:

```
[ApiVersion("1")]
    [RoutePrefix("orders")]
    [Description("doc0x03303001")]
    public class OrdersController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly OrdersManager _mng;

        //public OrdersController(){}

        public OrdersController(OrdersManager mng)
        {
            if (mng == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mng));

            _mng = mng;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult GetTeste()
        {
            _mng.ReceiveAssessment("ok", "ok", "ok", 1);
            return Ok("");
        }
    }
```

O método ReceiveAssessment é este(apenas para testar se entra ou não no método)

```
public void ReceiveAssessment(string assessment, string claimNumber, string registerNumber, int code)
        {
            string _assessment = assessment;
            string _claimnumber = claimNumber;
            string _registernumber = registerNumber;
            int _code = code;
        }
```

abaixo a OrdersManager

```
public class OrdersManager : IDisposable, IOrdersManager
    {

        private OrdersManagement _mng;
        private OrderDist _orderDist;
        private SystemAssessment _systemAssessment;
        private BlackListSupplier _blacklistsuplier;

        public OrdersManager(string idUser, string login, string timezone,
            string idCompany, string idCompanyType)
        {
            _mng = new OrdersManagement(idUser, login, timezone, idCompany, idCompanyType);
        }


        public void ReceiveAssessment(string assessment, string claimNumber, string registerNumber, int code)
        {
            string _assessment = assessment;
            string _claimnumber = claimNumber;
            string _registernumber = registerNumber;
            int _code = code;


        }

        #region IDisposable Support
        private bool disposedValue = false; // To detect redundant calls

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!disposedValue)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    // TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects).
                }

                // TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override a finalizer below.
                //TODO: SSO
                //_mng?.Dispose();
                // TODO: set large fields to null.

                disposedValue = true;
            }
        }

        // TODO: override a finalizer only if Dispose(bool disposing) above has code to free unmanaged resources.
        ~OrdersManager()
        {
            // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in Dispose(bool disposing) above.
            Dispose(false);
        }

        // This code added to correctly implement the disposable pattern.
        public void Dispose()
        {
            // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in Dispose(bool disposing) above.
            Dispose(true);
            // TODO: uncomment the following line if the finalizer is overridden above.
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

OrdersManager é um objeto, como informei acima. Como eu faço para entrar na controller e continuar executando a API?

Os erros são concatenados em uma classe(um array de erros) e abaixo eu os coloquei, os pegos nas configurações passadas acima, sendo que eu chamo a action GetTeste e não receiveassessment.

> > {
> >         "message": "An error has occurred.",
> >
> > ```
> > "exceptionMessage": "The specified API version is invalid.",
> >
> > "exceptionType": "System.FormatException",
> >
> > "stackTrace": "   at Microsoft.Web.Http.ApiVersion.Parse(String text)\r\n   at
> > ```
> >
> > System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()\r\n   at
> >     System.Linq.Enumerable.<DistinctIterator>d__64`1.MoveNext()\r\n   at
> >     System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at
> >     System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at
> >     Microsoft.Web.Http.CollectionExtensions.ToSortedReadOnlyList[T](IEnumerable`1
> >     sequence)\r\n   at
> >     Microsoft.Web.Http.Versioning.ApiVersionsBaseAttribute.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<.ctor>b__1()\r\n
> >     at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()\r\n   at
> >     System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()\r\n   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()\r\n
> >
> >     at
> >     Microsoft.Web.Http.Versioning.ApiVersionsBaseAttribute.get_Versions()\r\n
> >     at
> >     System.Web.Http.AttributeExtensions.<>c__0`1.b__0_1(T
> >     attribute)\r\n   at
> >     System.Linq.Enumerable.d__23`3.MoveNext()\r\n   at
> >     System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at
> >     System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.d__1.MoveNext()\r\n
> >     at
> >     System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()\r\n 
> >     at System.Linq.Enumerable.<DistinctIterator>d__64`1.MoveNext()\r\n
> >     at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at
> >     System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at
> >     System.Web.Http.AttributeExtensions.GetImplementedApiVersions[T](IEnumerable`1
> >     attributes)\r\n   at
> >     Microsoft.Web.Http.Versioning.ApiVersionModel.GetDeclaredControllerApiVersions(HttpControllerDescriptor
> >     controllerDescriptor)\r\n   at
> >     Microsoft.Web.Http.Versioning.ApiVersionModel.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<.ctor>b__0()\r\n
> >     at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()\r\n   at
> >     System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()\r\n   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()\r\n
> >
> >     at
> >     Microsoft.Web.Http.Versioning.ApiVersionModelExtensions.Aggregate(ApiVersionModel
> >     version, IEnumerable`1 otherVersions)\r\n   at
> >     System.Web.Http.HttpControllerDescriptorExtensions.AggregateVersions(IEnumerable`1
> >     controllerDescriptors)\r\n   at
> >     Microsoft.Web.Http.Dispatcher.ApiVersionControllerAggregator.AggregateAllCandiateVersions()\r\n
> >     at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()\r\n   at
> >     System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()\r\n   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()\r\n
> >     at
> >     Microsoft.Web.Http.Dispatcher.ConventionRouteControllerSelector.SelectController(ApiVersionControllerAggregator
> >     aggregator)\r\n   at
> >     Microsoft.Web.Http.Dispatcher.ApiVersionControllerSelector.SelectController(HttpRequestMessage
> >     request)\r\n   at
> >     System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__15.MoveNext()"
> >     }

Quando o compilador pula o construtor com mparâmetros, ele cai aqui primeiro:

```
protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var responseMessage = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

            object contentVal;
            if (!responseMessage.TryGetContentValue(out contentVal))
                return responseMessage;

            if (contentVal == null)
                return responseMessage;

            ConvertDateTimeDeep(contentVal);

            var processedResponse = request.CreateResponse(responseMessage.StatusCode, contentVal);
            responseMessage.Content = processedResponse.Content;
            return responseMessage;
        }
```

No método acima, na linha `var responseMessage = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);` já explode o stauscode 500(Internal Server Error). Já a var(object) contentVal é onde eu pego os erros e quando eu chamo `ConvertDateTimeDeep` passando contentVal, já zica tudo. Só queria entender porque ele não entra no Construtor.

ConvertDateTimeDeep

```
private void ConvertDateTimeDeep(object contentVal)
        {
            var scannedObjects = new HashSet<object>(new[] { contentVal });
            var userTimeZone = HttpContext.Current.GetUserTimeZone();
            if (typeof(IDictionary<object, object>).IsAssignableFrom(contentVal.GetType()))
            {
                var collection = (contentVal as IDictionary<object, object>).Values;
                foreach (var item in collection)
                    ConvertDateTimeDeep(item, userTimeZone, scannedObjects);
            }
            else if (typeof(IDictionary<string, object>).IsAssignableFrom(contentVal.GetType()))
            {
                var collection = (contentVal as IDictionary<string, object>).Values;
                foreach (var item in collection)
                    ConvertDateTimeDeep(item, userTimeZone, scannedObjects);
            }
            else if (typeof(IEnumerable<object>).IsAssignableFrom(contentVal.GetType()))
            {
                var enumerable = contentVal as IEnumerable<object>;
                foreach (var item in enumerable)
                    ConvertDateTimeDeep(item, userTimeZone, scannedObjects);
            }
            else
                ConvertDateTimeDeep(contentVal, userTimeZone, scannedObjects);
        }
```

Quando eu troco a rota na controller para essa

```
[Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
    [Description("doc0x03303001")]
    public class OrdersController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly OrdersManager _mng;
        private readonly IOrdersManager _mngs;

        //public OrdersController(){}

        public OrdersController(IOrdersManager mng)
        {
            if (mng == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mng));

            _mngs = mng;
        }
}
```

pego o erro abaixo no postman

> {
>       "message": "An error has occurred.",
>       "exceptionMessage": "Parameter count mismatch.",
>       "exceptionType": "System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException",
>       "stackTrace": "   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj,
>   BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters,
>   CultureInfo culture)\r\n   at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo
>   culture)\r\n   at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj,
>   BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo
>   culture)\r\n   at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[]
>   index)\r\n   at System.Reflection.PropertyInfo.GetValue(Object
>   obj)\r\n   at
>   Solera.Solaris.CentralV2.Orders.Business.Http.UtcDateTimeToLocalDateTimeConverterHandler.ConvertDateTimeRecursive(PropertyInfo
>   prop, Object owner, TimeZoneInfo userTimeZone, ISet`1 scannedObjs) in
>   C:\\Projetos\\nova_central_v3\\nova_central_v3\\src\\CentralAPI\\Services\\Orders\\Business\\Http\\UtcDateTimeToLocalDateTimeConverterHandler.cs:line
>   113\r\n   at
>   Solera.Solaris.CentralV2.Orders.Business.Http.UtcDateTimeToLocalDateTimeConverterHandler.ConvertDateTimeDeep(Object
>   contentVal, TimeZoneInfo userTimeZone, ISet`1 scannedObjs) in
>   C:\Projetos\nova_central_v3\nova_central_v3\src\CentralAPI\Services\Orders\Business\Http\UtcDateTimeToLocalDateTimeConverterHandler.cs:line
>   77\r\n   at
>   Solera.Solaris.CentralV2.Orders.Business.Http.UtcDateTimeToLocalDateTimeConverterHandler.ConvertDateTimeDeep(Object
>   contentVal) in
>   C:\Projetos\nova_central_v3\nova_central_v3\src\CentralAPI\Services\Orders\Business\Http\UtcDateTimeToLocalDateTimeConverterHandler.cs:line
>   57\r\n   at
>   Solera.Solaris.CentralV2.Orders.Business.Http.UtcDateTimeToLocalDateTimeConverterHandler.d__2.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\Projetos\nova_central_v3\nova_central_v3\src\CentralAPI\Services\Orders\Business\Http\UtcDateTimeToLocalDateTimeConverterHandler.cs:line
>   36\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception
>   was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.d__24.MoveNext()"
>   }

Comment: inclua um exemplo do post que está fazendo

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, essa é a chamada no Postman: `http://localhost:24253/api/v1/orders/receiveassessment`

Comment: Você não tem essa rota em sua controller

Comment: Alterando a rota, peguei esse erro: **An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'OrdersController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.**

Comment: Na edição dos erros, falei que havia 4 erros, mas na verdade é um só, apenas a classe os sepaou, mas o erro é um só. Leia tudo de uma vez e não erro 1, erro 2 e etc. Vou editar e colocar como se fosse um único erro

Answer (score 0):

Tente trocar esse trecho

```
[ApiVersion("1")]
```

Por esse:

```
[ApiVersion("v1")]
```

Comment: De 5 caiu para 4 erros, mas com essa mensagem após trocar de 1 para v1: **The specified API version is invalid.**

Comment: Você tinha comentado que o código não parava no breakpoint da Action. Acho melhor você postar todos os erros que o visual studio indica.

Comment: Eu sei, só que agora é que eu vi que tem uma classe que vai concatenando os erros. Não conhecia isso ainda, hj é meu segundo dia e já tenho essa bucha, mas tudo que eu levantar aqui, estarei postando para tentar esclarecer e ajudar mais.